# Use output of Solve as input of another instance of Solve. How to deal with list of rules

Tags: equation-solving, system

I am a complete novice with Mathematica. The last line of the code that I report is a system of equations I'd like to solve (and I am sure it admits a unique solution): (I don't know how I can convert the greek letters in the code block... I hope that copy-pasting on Mathematica is sufficient, which seems the case... Let me know if I need to do something else to ease copy-pasting for respondents for the future)

```
Un = \[Theta] - p;
Ur = \[Delta]*\[Theta] - r ;
Vl = \[Theta] + (1 - f)*\[Theta] - p ;
Vr = \[Theta] + (1 - f)*\[Theta]  + f*(Ur) - p;
\[CapitalTheta]rn = Solve[Un == Ur, \[Theta]];
\[CapitalTheta]or = Solve[Vr ==  0, \[Theta]] ;

Dn1 = 1 - \[CapitalTheta]or + f*(1 - \[CapitalTheta]rn);
Dr1  = f*(\[CapitalTheta]rn - \[CapitalTheta]or);

\[CapitalPi]1 = (p - c)*Dn1 +  r*Dr1;


{ps1, rs1} = {p, r} /. Simplify[Solve[{D[\[CapitalPi]1, p] == 0,
      D[\[CapitalPi]1, r] == 0}, {p, r}]][[1]]
```

EDIT: I also add the line with the greek letters:

```
Un = θ - p;
Ur = δ*θ - r ;
Vl = θ + (1 - f)*θ - p ;
Vr = θ + (1 - f)*θ  + f*(Ur) - p;
Θrn = θ/.Solve[Un == Ur, θ][[1,1]];
Θor = θ/.Solve[Vr ==  0, θ][[1,1]];

Dn1 = 1 - Θor + f*(1 - Θrn);
Dr1  = f*(Θrn - Θor);
Π1 = (p - c)*Dn1 +  r*Dr1;
{ps1, rs1} = {p, r}/.Simplify[Solve[{D[Π1, p] == 0,      D[Π1, r] == 0}, {p, r}]][[1]]
```

The Last line, which is adapted from the code of a friend and where I don't fully grasp what `/.` and `[[1]]` , yields the following errors:

```
Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

ReplaceAll::reps: {{{1+f+(c+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]) (0->Power[<<2>>])+f (c+Times[<<2>>]+r) (0->Power[<<2>>])-(\[Theta]->Times[<<2>>])-f (\[Theta]->Times[<<2>>])}}==0,{{(c+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]) (0->Times[<<2>>])+f (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Rule[<<2>>])}}==0} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

Set::shape: Lists {ps1,rs1} and {p,r}/. {{{1+f+Plus[<<3>>] Rule[<<2>>]+f Plus[<<3>>] Rule[<<2>>]-Rule[<<2>>]-f Rule[<<2>>]}}==0,{{Plus[<<3>>] Rule[<<2>>]+f Plus[<<3>>]}}==0} are not the same shape.
```

I understood that this is related somewhat to the curly brackets. But I didn't really get to what extent... Can anyone help me?

Comment: From your code with Greek letters I get the answer: `{(2 + c + c f)/(2 + 2 f), (1 - f + \[Delta] + f \[Delta])/(2 + 2 f)}` I am using MMA version 13.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work better.

```
Un = θ - p;
Ur = δ*θ - r ;
Vl = θ + (1 - f)*θ - p ;
Vr = θ + (1 - f)*θ  + f*(Ur) - p;
Θrn = θ/.Solve[Un == Ur, θ][[1,1]];
Θor = θ/.Solve[Vr ==  0, θ][[1,1]];

Dn1 = 1 - Θor + f*(1 - Θrn);
Dr1  = f*(Θrn - Θor);
Π1 = (p - c)*Dn1 +  r*Dr1;
{ps1, rs1} = {p, r}/.Simplify[Solve[{D[Π1, p] == 0,      D[Π1, r] == 0}, {p, r}]][[1]]
```

The mysterious `/.` is short for [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html). Because [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) returns a list of rules for all solutions, you can use it as the argument for `ReplaceAll`.

The `[[1,1]]` is short por [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

I recommend that you verify your [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) assignments , for example you were doing

```
Θor = Solve[Vr ==  0, θ]
```

[image]

But most likely you want

```
Θor = θ/.Solve[Vr ==  0, θ][[1,1]];
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks! How did you transform the greek letters? Did you manually type them?

Comment: For Greek letters and other symbols in SE [see here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/10397)

Comment: Wow, this is magical! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand that [[1]]  is then the first element of the list, namely the [0] in Python. However, I don't fully understand what does [[1,1]] stand for! Does it mean it takes the first element of expression [[1]]?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentatiuon for `Part`, including the *Details*. `expr[[i,j]]` or `Part[expr,i,j]` is equivalent to `expr[[i]][[j]]`. So `[[1,1]]` is the first element of the first element, like `First@*First`.

Comment: I read the documentation, yet I still don't understand what "the first element of the first element" means. In my case, it should irrelevant whether I type `[[1]]` or `[[1,1]]`, right?

Comment: In this case is irrelevant because the argument for `ReplaceAll` can be either a `Rule` or a `List` of `Rule`s.  You could also use `Θor = θ /. First@Solve[Vr ==  0, θ]`

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli the case `{{a}}` might be a bit confusing for understanding `Part`. Consider that a special case of something more general like `list={{a1,a2},{b1,b2},{c1,c2}}` then you can obtain `{a1,a2}` with `list[[1]]` (first Part of list) and a1 with `list[[1]][[1]]` (1st part of 1st sublist ) or simply `list[[1,1]]`. You can obtain c1 with `list[[3,1]]` because to find it you go to the **3**rd part of list to find the sublist where it lives then you go to the **1**st part of that sublist. Consider also experimenting with `TreeForm`

Comment: @userrand Now I perfectly see the point, thanks a lot!